# power-shell retrieving line from array

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell

So if I create an array from CSV file

```
name,age,height,fruit
Jon,34,5,orange
Jane,23,4,apple
Dave,27,6,pear
```

I can read this in using

```
$list = Import-CSV .....
```

but now i have the question. "tell me about Jane"

So I could say

```
foreach ($val in $list)
{
    if ($val.name = "jane" ) {$currentuser = $val}
}

write-host $currentuser.name
write-host $currentuser.age
write-host $currentuser.hight
write-host $currentuser.fruit
```

Is there a better way to do this rather than stepping through? In my actually case i have a list of staff from HR and a separate one from Active directory.
I want to step through the HR list to find the user in AD, set this user as a variable/object. and then update the user using information from HR.

The above method will work but seems very inefficient to be loping through two lists of several thousand users.

Given the array created from the CSV, I want a method that by inputting the string "jane" it will return jane's info to a object i can use.

Comment: If I understand, then I think what you want is: ***$list | ?{$_.Name -eq 'jane'}***

Comment: Also great thank  you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two lists, both with distinct keys by which the two can be correlated, the best way is to store one list in a lookup table (any type of dictionary will do, including a hashtable in PowerShell), and then loop sequentially through the other list:

```
$HRList = @'
Name,Position,Department
John,Manager,Sales
Bob,Worker,Production
Sally,Accountant,Finance
'@ |ConvertFrom-Csv

$ADList = @'
Name,Username
Sally,sallysalt
Bob,bobburrows
John,johnjames
'@ |ConvertFrom-Csv

# Convert the AD list to a hash table
$ADLookupTable = @{}
foreach($ADUser in $ADList)
{
    $ADLookupTable[$ADUser.Name] = $ADUser
}

# Go through HR list
foreach($HRUser in $HRList)
{
    # Now you can find the relevant object in the other list
    $ADUser = $ADLookupTable[$HRUser.Name]
    Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.Username -Title $ADUser.Position -Department $ADUser.Department
}
```